# Azure Service Fabric Application

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Can you guys explain

1. Service Fabric can be packaged with MULTIPLE SERVICES to be shipped but then 
   how do you reuse some of these services into other Application?
2. Is there a way Reliable Dictionary or Reliable Queue may be shared among 
   services deployed on Same Cluster?

   I tried reading on google but no clear understanding. Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**... how do you reuse some of these services into other Application?**

What do you mean with reuse? Sharing the code? You could have a service in Application A talk to a service in Application B instead of having the same service in Application A.

**Is there a way Reliable Dictionary or Reliable Queue may be shared among services deployed on Same Cluster?**

No there is not. A Reliable Dictionary or Reliable Queue provides data locality to a service removing the need for additional network calls. As soon as you need this same data for multiple services you should consider using other storage solutions like CosmosDB, Blob storage or another database.

If you are looking for some kind of distributed cache you can take a look at Azure Redis.

It is, however, entirely possible to expose the data of a Reliable Dictionary or Reliable Queue using a service. Then that service acts like a data provider / repository. You can expose methods like Add() or Delete() in such a service that results in an update of the Reliable Dictionary or Reliable Queue.